# Web page countdown timer and automatic submit

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am doing an online exam project.  I want to submit a page after 10 minutes, even if the user doesn't click on the submit button.  Also, I want to display a countdown of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be fairly straight-forward, just use `[setInterval][1]` to do the countdown and submit the postback.

```
<div id="timer"></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var start = new Date();
    setInterval(function() {
        // check time elapsed given target time of 10 mins from now
        var timeLeft = (600000 - (new Date() - start))/1000;
        // update timer
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = Math.floor(timeLeft/60) + ":" + Math.floor(timeLeft%60);

        // check if timer has elapsed, and submit form
        if (timeLeft > 0) {
            document.forms[0].submit();
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

**Edit** Per the comments, the it's best to check the actual time elapsed, rather than relying on *setInterval* (which is not perfectly accurate).

Comment: I wouldn't decrement a timer, instead calculate the difference between a start and end time. The interval of 1000ms won't be prefect and you'll loose/gain time...

Comment: @ChrisMoutray yes, very good point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "window.setTimeout" function to set the timeout of submitting form. For counting down, I'd suggest you to use a jquery plugin like this one: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Cheers

```
window.setTimeout(
    function ()
    {
        $("form")[0]
        .submit();
    },
    10000
);
```